# Properties as money

Tags: monopoly-deal

As per the rule, I can always make a "house"/"hotel" action card as money by simply putting it on my money stack. What I wanted to know is, can I do the same for properties too?

For example, I can see another player needs only one property of the set to win the game, and I have that one property card. Just as bad sportsmanship, can I make that property as currency by putting it on the money stack to kind of "burn" the property?

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot. The rules specifically state that action, house, or hotel cards can be played as cash. No such provision is made for properties - you must play them as properties. If you want to block your opponent, your only option is to not play the property at all.

Comment: I was going through the rules and there isn't any mention that properties **cannot** be used as cash. Actually its like they have mentioned only about action cards.

Answer (score 1):

You can also devise a way to get more than 7 cards at the end of your turn (Repeated Pass Gos/Not playing any cards on that turn) and then since you have to discard cards at the end of the turn, you can discard that property to kind of "burn" it.
However,

- The 3 sets of properties that have 2 cards in a set have 5 cards that can be used for the 2 properties (2 originals + 1 2-coloured wild + 2 multi-coloured wild)
- The 6 sets of properties that have 3 cards in a set have 7 (3+2+2)
- Railroads have 9 (4+3+2)

So unless you have the last (or last few) cards for the person to complete the set, your efforts in "burning" then property will be wasted.